# 10 second delay (can't scroll or click buttons) even after browser's loading spinner finishes and everything appears on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

The browser's loading spinner stops and the all of the initial content of the page appears as if it is ready to go. However, all of the buttons are frozen and I can't scroll for at least 10 seconds after the page becomes visible and the browser's spinner stops.

This page has several different views that are set to display: none; on initial load of the page. I am assuming it is all client that is causing the delay since the browser's loading spinner finishes.

Can someone tell me what kind of delay this is and how I can possibly show a loading spinner in the middle of the page until the page is ready to go.

I have about 20 Kendo Charts loading on the page and several html tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply a javascript overload - Kendo UI is heavily manipulating and changing the DOM. I personally got similar problems. The Best Solution is inspect the Javascript Usage with the Developer Tools that are included in the common browsers. Why do you have so much Widgets at one Place or Site? Try to load if needed - not everything at once.